# Cannot resolve symbol 'setText' (android button)

Tags: android, button, settext

I would like to change the text in a button, but the setText method doesn't work, it marks it in red and says symbol not resolved. How can i fix this? Here is my code.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        int partA = 9;
        int partB = 9;
        int correctAnswer = partA * partB;
        int wrongAnswer1 = correctAnswer++;
        int wrongAnswer2 = correctAnswer--;
    }


    TextView textObjectA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartA);
    TextView textObjectB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartB);

    Button buttonObjectChoice1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
    Button buttonObjectChoice2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);
    Button buttonObjectChoice3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);

    //this part doesn't work   
    buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + partA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your code

```
TextView textObjectA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartA);
TextView textObjectB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPartB);

Button buttonObjectChoice1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
Button buttonObjectChoice2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);
Button buttonObjectChoice3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);

//this part doesn't work   
buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + partA);
```

into onCreate() method.

Comment: it worked, thank you